# how to change controller name in url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I have a "HomeController" and my route is like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home", action ="Index", id =    UrlParameter.Optional
            }   
        );
```

I want url be like "web-design/Index" instead of "Home/Index".
how can i do that ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
  // add a new route
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "homepage",
        url: "web-design/{action}",
        defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", action ="Index"
        }   
    );

  // add your default route but change the default action or controller
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", action ="SomeotherAction", id =    UrlParameter.Optional
        }   
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want  "web-design/Index" to be the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
        controller = "web-design", action ="Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional
        }   
    );
```

Comment: i cant name a controller "web-design" , what can i do about this?